# Loading data from another file using Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am trying to get myself started with Ajax so I was just trying to load some content from a file on click of a button but the content of other file is not loaded

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function loadData()
            {
                var xmlhttp;
                if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
                {
                    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
                }
                else
                {
                    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
                {
                    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                    {                                    
                        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                    }
                }
                xmlhttp.open("GET","a1.html",true);
                xmlhttp.send();
            }
        </script>
        </head>
        <body>    
            <h2>AJAX</h2>
            <button type="button" onclick="loadData()">Request data</button>
            <div id="output"></div>    
        </body>
</html>
```

a1.html file is present under same folder where this html file is.

Comment: Are you sure the path is correct, check again..

Comment: please check that "a1.html" file will be in the same folder where the above file is located.

Comment: Your code is working fine for me.

Answer (score 2):

I got it , I must request the page from a server. not just localhost

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm. everything looks good with this code. Maybe you should check if the file exists.
You can also use local files with AJAX and not only urls with a server address.